# Автозаполнение реквизитов по ИНН

Tags: c#

подскажите как получить реквизиты компаний по ИНН.
 Сведения о контрагентах есть в ЕГРИП, ЕГРЮЛ.
 https://egrul.nalog.ru/
может есть бесплатные ресурсы? кто нибудь делал такое?
 https://focus.kontur.ru/entity?query=1077758307252
    на данном сайте можно получить реквизиты по ИНН однако сервис работает непосредственно на сайте.Никаких капч и прочих наворотов, можно элементарно получать GET-запросом страницу и либо показывать её пользователю, но в итоге как правильнее получить эти данные в программу...

Comment: Я пользуюсь сервисом dadata.ru, позволяет все это делать, удобное апи

Comment: dadata.ru - да.